# IIS Cannot Start Application Pool - using DFS, Shared Config and Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: iis-8

I deploy sites using Microsoft.Web.Administration in C#. I deploy to a single server, and using DFS and IIS Shared Config am able to propagate my changes out to the other servers that sit behind a load balancer.

This was all working fine for some time and then I started to get issues. On the server that the code talks to it's fine, but on the other servers the app pool won't start, either automatically as part of the code deployment or manually by going onto each server and pressing start in the console.

[The object identifier does not represent a valid object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2eeb.png)

The current workaround for me is to open the app pool in the console (double click) and then press ok, without doing anything else, and then I can start it and the site works.

Note that if i create an app pool manually on any of the servers, the same issue happens on the others, so I don't believe it to be a code issue with the deployment side of things.

Looking at the shared config file that is being replicated, there is no change to it whatsoever before and after doing the open and close thing on the app pool.

There are no messages in the event log that are proving useful and of my searching on the net I've only found 1 other person talking about something similar, and that thread remained unsolved. The error message is vague and searching it brings back all sorts of thing's, none of which are what I am experiencing.

This is on Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5

First time posting so if I've missed something or whatever I appreciate the feedback, thanks.

Comment: There seems to be no explicit statement that shared configuration works for DFS. You might contact Microsoft support via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, only thing is I had it working just fine, up until about 500 or so sites were deployed. I will contact them also but hoping someone else may have had a similar issue and can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code resolves the issue, hope it can help someone.

```
$sites = Get-Website | where {$_.state -eq $null}
$sites | ForEach-Object {
    $siteName = $_.name
    $appPoolName = $_.applicationPool
    IF (($siteName -ne $NULL) -and ($appPoolName -ne $NULL)){ 
        Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$siteName" ApplicationPool $appPoolName
    }
}
```